# Hi I'm trying to install ruby and stuck at the password prompt as I have not set up a password for my mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails

WARNING: Improper use of the sudo command could lead to data loss
or the deletion of important system files. Please double-check your
typing when using sudo. Type "man sudo" for more information.

To proceed, enter your password, or type Ctrl-C to abort.

Password:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution it seems to be simple, just set a password for your Mac OSX login as the [documentation support](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202035) says, there's no other way to do that without a password.

Comment: Thank you so much! Im a total novice hence the obvious question. This linked worked for me: http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/reset-forgotten-admin-password-mac-osx/

Comment: I'm glad that my answer was useful :). You can mark it as accepted if you think it was helpful n_n